# How to extract information for python error output

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I am trying to extract the information for the code I am writing. For example, when I write this code:

```
code = "hello"
code[10]
```

the output I would get from python is as followed:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_24520/526779498.py in <module>
----> 1 code[10]

IndexError: string index out of range
```

But when I implement a try except loop on the code:

```
code  = "hello"

try:
    code[10]
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

my output only shows me:

```
string index out of range
```

What would I need to do in order to extract the text "IndexError". Also, if there are any libraries that are useful to extract python errors for logging please let me know as well. Thank you.

Comment: if you just want to print the exception type you could use `print(e.__class__.__name__)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the name attribute of the exception

```
code  = "hello"

try:
    code[10]
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e).__name__)
```

Output:

```
IndexError
```

To get the full trace back you can use `traceback` like so

```
import traceback

code  = "hello"

try:
    code[10]
except Exception:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: Thanks for this Patrick, I would like to ask whether it would also be possible to extract the information of `Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_24520/526779498.py in <module>
----> 1 code[10]` What commands would be needed to be used to call for that specific information?

Comment: @codingnewb i have edited the answer to include the code for printing the full traceback